# openCSV library removing quotes from variable

Tags: java, json, opencsv

I am attempting to parse a csv file with opencsv. The last column in the file has a parameter which is actually json. This json is enclosed in "". The problem is opencsv is removing some " from inside the json causing my code to break.

```
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("c:\\Json.csv"), ',');
nextLine = reader.readNext();
        nextLine[6];
```

Has anyone seen this before?

example of json as found in the csv

```
"{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-66.9,18.05],[-66.9,18.05]]]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, your JSON is not valid CSV format unless you escape the quotation marks you want to keep. Double quote characters can be escaped with an additional double quote character ([as mentioned in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)) or with a backslash (as expected by the default parameters in CSVReader).

So in your example, the CSV content should be:

```
"{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[-66.9,18.05],[-66.9,18.05]]]}"
```

or

```
"{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-66.9,18.05],[-66.9,18.05]]]}"
```

If you want it to be read/parsed *with* all the internal quotation marks (but *without* the surrounding quotation marks). CSVReader will read both as:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-66.9,18.05],[-66.9,18.05]]]}
```

Also note that you can tell CSVReader to use different characters for quotes and escaping, but you should probably stick with the default since they are more universally accepted.

Comment: Did some find and replaced and fixed all of that. Thanks for pointing it out, I would have ran into this problem down the line when trying to read this json in the visualization I am creating.